# Form Button is not working with unless condition - Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

Everything is showing like I expect but the send button is not working.
the button is not clickable as well

This part is for product-form.liquid

```
{% unless product.available %}

{%- form 'contact', id: form_id -%}
    {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
    <p class="accent-text">Thanks! We will notify you when this product becomes available!</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Enter your email to get notified when {{ product.title }} become available.</p>
    {% endif %}
 
   
    <div id="notify-me-wrapper" class="clearfix">
      {% if customer %}
      <input type="hidden" name="contact[email]" value="{{ customer.email }}" />
      {% else %}
      <input style="float:left; width:180px;" required="required" type="email" name="contact[email]" placeholder="your@email.com" class="styled-input" />
      {% endif %}
      <input type="hidden" name="contact[body]" value="Please notify me when {{ product.title | escape }} becomes available." />
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn">
          {{ 'contact.form.send' | t }}
        </button>
  {% endform %}

{% endunless %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code on my store. there is no error in the liquid code. it may possible that some js code is being affected after page load. please check your JS files.